# Can the uv_write() send a large amount of data at one time?

Tags: libuv

For example, my buffer to send has 20K bytes (user lists).

I wonder if uv_write() can send the 20K bytes at once, not sepearted.
So will the callback function, after_write_cb, returns the status 0 of success?

That is, Don't I need to care about the leftover while sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass megabyte sized buffers to `uv_write` if you want, libuv will only call the write callback after **all** data has been sent.

Comment: Thank again for answering again, saghul. I feel libuv easy to use.